# rails 4 has many through association query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, has-many-through

I have these models, but when I do a Message.last.people or Message.last.recipient_lists I get an error. How would I reference the Recipient Lists or people attached to a message with active record? Would I need to do a `RecipientList.where(:message => Message.last)` ? Seems like there should be a better way to do it through the .message ?

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many   :people, through: :recipient_list
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages, through: :recipient_list
end

class RecipientList < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :person
    belongs_to :message
end
```

I get this error

> Message.last.recipient_lists
>   Message Load (0.7ms)  SELECT
>   "messages".* FROM "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
>   NoMethodError: undefined method `recipient_lists' for
>
> ## from /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activemodel-4.0.9/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:439:in
>
> `method_missing'  from
>   /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/activerecord-4.0.9/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:168:in`
>   method_missing'  from (irb):1    from
>   /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in
>   `start'   from
>   /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in`
>   start'   from
>   /home/nick/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/railties-4.0.9/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in
>   `<top (required)>'    from bin/rails:4:in`require'   from bin/rails:4:in
>   `'
>
> Message.last.people   Message Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "messages".* FROM
>   "messages" ORDER BY "messages"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
>   ActiveRecord::HasManyThroughAssociationNotFoundError: Could not find
>   the association :recipient_list in model Message

Comment: You fail to state the error.  Is it something about a `nil` perchance?

Comment: @DavidHoelzer edited with error messages for the queries Message.last.recipient_lists and Message.last.people

Comment: Did you run the migrations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly include `has_many :recipient_lists` in both Message and Person, and also correctly pluralize `:recipient_lists` in the `through:` option, like so:

```
class Message < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipient_lists
  has_many :people, through: :recipient_lists
end

class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :recipient_lists
  has_many :messages, through: :recipient_lists
end

class RecipientList < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :message
end
```